# How to use the value of a variable as a property

Tags: php, phpexcel

I wrote a PHP-Skript that uses PHPExcel. It should use a config-file to create a spreadsheet. My problem comes up, when i try to apply styles.

I created a style-array from the informations given in the config-file. Now, when it comes to e.g. alignment of cells or borders you would use something like

```
'horizontal' => PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER
```

where `HORIZONTAL_CENTER` is the desired property. Now, I have this property-name stored in a variable and I cannot use something like

```
'horizontal' => PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::$variableWithPropertyName
```

but I need the value of the variable to be used because there can be different properties.

Any ideas?

Comment: I forgot to mention that of course the fatal error "Access to undeclared static property: PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::$layoutValues" appears! $layoutValues has the desired property name.

Comment: I'm going to take a wild guess here and say you declared `$layoutValues` as non-static. You can access it using `$this`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$alignmentsArray = (new ReflectionClass('PHPExcel_Style_Alignment'))->getConstants();
```

should return an array of possible alignment values, indexed by their name, so you can then set

```
'horizontal' => $alignmentsArray[$variableWithPropertyName]
```

where `$variableWithPropertyName` is your value like `HORIZONTAL_CENTER`

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the Reflection API to retrieve the value, like so:

```
$property = new ReflectionProperty('PHPExcel_Style_Alignment', $variableWithPropertyName);
```

And the value can then be retrieved like so:

```
'horizontal' => $property->getValue();
```

Comment: [getClassConstants()](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getconstants.php) would be better than using ReflectionProperty, because these are all class constants